# How to get a router-link to act as a button and still be tabindex and clickable?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a sidebar component which has some links that change the page but then also on one icon which is a search icon it expands the sidebar and there is a searchbar there. However, if I click on this search icon then the url changes which messes up my query parameters for vue-router. I just want this item to act as a button in a sense and to be accessable from tab like all other links and clickable via the return key similar to how my other router-links are.

```
                <div class="main-menu-items">
                    <ul>
                        <li v-for="(item,i) in MainNavLinks"
                            :key="i"
                            :class="{'active-main-menu-item': i === activeIconIndex}"
                            v-on:click="selectIconItem(i,$event)">
                            <router-link :to="item.link">
                                <i :class="item.icon"></i>
                            </router-link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

My array I loop through makes the link # for the search but again it still changes the URL which I do not want. Can this even be done? A lot of my formatting is based on a which router-link generates so I didnt want to have to single this one item out.

```
                MainNavLinks: [
                {
                    name: 'Dashboard',
                    link: '/',
                    icon: 'fa-solid fa-house fa-md',
                    sidebar: false,
                    component: '',
                    SubNavLinks: []
                },
                {
                    name: 'Search',
                    link: '#',
                    icon: 'fas fa-search fa-md',
                    sidebar: true,
                    component: 'sidebarsearch',
                    SubNavLinks:[],
                },
            ],
```

Comment: I think you need to prevent the default action, so try using `v-on:click.prevent` or if you call a function use `e.preventDefault()` while passing the `e` parameter as the event to the function.